# Why is there no type error when using copy with spread

Tags: typescript

I make a copy of the array of objects through the map function. Why does not an error occur with a new property "xxx"?  New property "xxx" is not declared in the interface?

```
interface A{
  a:number;
  b:string;
};

let a:A[] = [{a:1, b:"a"}, {a:2, b:"b"}];

let b:A[] = a.map((x)=>({...x, xxx:"abc"}));
```

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only done when directly creating an object where it's used, e.g., `foo({a: 1, b: "a", "xx"})` will fail the excess property check, `obj = {a: 1, b: "a", "xx"}; foo(obj)` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Because variable `b` still assignable to `a`.

Consider next example:

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

interface B {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  xxx: string;
}

declare var a: A[]
declare var b: B[]

a = b // ok
b = a // error
```

`b` contains all properties from `a`, so it is safe to assign `b` to `a`.

From the other hand, it is not save to assign `a` to `b`.

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

interface B {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  xxx: string;
}


let a:B[] = [{a:1, b:"a"}, {a:2, b:"b"}]; // error
```

Because they are covariant.

If you are looking for contravariance, consider this example:

```js
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

interface B {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  xxx: string;
}

class C<T>{
  method = (a: T) => { }
}

let a: C<A> = new C()
let b: C<B> = new C()

// vice versa
a = b // error
b = a // ok
```